# Is it possible to get redis-benchmark in Azure Portal's Redis Console?

Tags: azure, redis, azureportal

I'm running redis cache in azure. Azure Portal provides a console for the redis server to run redis commands (`get [key]` works). I wanted to use *redis-benchmarks* but its throwing an error: `(error) ERR unknown command`. This is slightly confusing because Redis supposedly includes [*redis-benchmark*](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks).

> Redis includes the *redis-benchmark* utility that simulates running commands done by N clients at the same time sending M total queries (it is similar to the Apache's ab utility).

Is there a way to get *redis-benchmark* to work?

Here's an example command from the article: `redis-benchmark -q -n 100000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run the `redis-benchmark` inside a redis-cli shell. It's not part of the redis commands. Try to run the redis-benchmark from a regular shell prompt instead.

Not working:

```
C:\>redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> redis-benchmark -t set,get -r 1000000 -q
(error) ERR unknown command 'redis-benchmark'
```

Working:

```
C:\>redis-benchmark -t set,get -r 1000000 -q
SET: 111856.82 requests per second
GET: 108225.10 requests per second
```

Comment: I haven't tried this since I had the problem almost 2 years ago but this seems like the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The Console in Azure only supports redis-cli. To use Redis-benchmark, you need to turn on the non SSL port in Azure Redis Cache. More details are https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#cache-commands

Answer (score 0):

You can also run these command from your local machine. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-faq#how-can-i-run-redis-commands)

> You can use any of the commands listed at Redis commands except for the commands listed at Redis commands not supported in Azure Cache for Redis. You have several options to run Redis commands.
>
> - If you have a Standard or Premium cache, you can run Redis commands using the Redis Console. The Redis console provides a secure way to run Redis commands in the Azure portal.
> - You can also use the Redis command-line tools. To use them, perform the following steps:
> - Download the Redis command-line tools.
> - Connect to the cache using redis-cli.exe. Pass in the cache endpoint using the -h switch and the key using -a as shown in the following example:
>   redis-cli -h .redis.cache.windows.net -a